# How can I change currency sign to superscript across all magento 2 product prices?

Tags: magento2, currency, product, price

I want to change currency symbol (£) to go superscript for all products across the shop. How can I do that? I believe prices are generated via JavaScript in magento 2?! I have added the image what I want to achieve. Thanks in advance!

[Here is the sample image of how it should look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmVNA.png)

Comment: Use utf-8 charcter

Comment: @SumeshTG thanks, but I would like to know how can I implement that change to the template in Magento 2. I have tried editing price rendering template but its not working.